# In Material theme how can I change cursor color on error for textfield?

Tags: android, material-design, textfield

I'm using material outlined texfield in my layout and I want to change cursor and pointer color to red but only on error. So basically I want my cursor to match the outline color at all times (primary color when focused and red on error). Does anybody know how to do this?

I'm using MaterialComponents theme in my app and in my TextInputLayout I'm using @style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox. Everything according to the official documentation.

I know I can customize my theme and change accent color but I don't know how to change it in runtime (I want it red only on error).

I also know I can set custom cursor drawable but it won't change the pointer. I could probably set custom pointer drawable too (?) but then I'd have to make it as pretty as the default one and that sounds hard.

And obviously I don't want to set cursor drawable to null and make it match the text color. My text color is black and my cursor color is supposed to be my primary color when focused and red on error.

So I'm kinda running out of ideas.

Does anybody know how to do this?

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0-alpha07'
```

In styles:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"/>
```

In layout:

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/title_wrapper"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
        app:hintEnabled="true"
        android:hint="Title">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/title_edittext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: What API version are you targeting?

Comment: I want to target API 21+

Comment: Are you using data binding?

Comment: No, I don't event know what that is. Is it supposed to help?